# Android Bitmap Stretching/Pinching

Tags: android, android-image

I am hoping this question/issue is not too vague as I have tried asking something earlier but seemed to have came to a dead end.

Basically I am looking at stretching/pinching parts of a Bitmap within my Android project. There would be coordinates passed to the function in order to indicate where the move would need to take place (x,y).

I need to find a way to shift pixels up and down (in either a line or arc type format) and allow the pixels in between to be warped accordingly (not disappear or hide).

A sample image of what I am trying to achieve would be something like:

I would paste an image here but apparently am not allowed yet. (Image URL: http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQtLEHS-ZRQs3p7XmeU2TM6Vwgfh7DGnh-5nDIDu3Yd7zTIR0zX)

(Just grabbed a random Google face warp)

I have read about a few things like openCV and javaCV but they seem like overkill. I am simply looking for something that might allow me to move an array of coordinates from a source point to destination and allow for a smooth warp.

Any help/information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Brad,

Heres a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004463/algorithm-for-a-smudge-tool) on how to create a smudge tool. That should help you create images like the one you included within your post.

Hope that helps!